# how to stop iframe console.log in Angular

Tags: typescript, iframe, console.log, angular11

How to stop iframe `console.log` in Angular 11,

i have

tried 1:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" [src]="myurl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen #chatRoom ng-onload="setChatRoom()"></iframe>

setChatRoom() {
    console.log = function() {console.log('no log')}
}
```

tried 2:

```
@ViewChild('chatRoom', {static: false}) chatRoom: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chatRoom.nativeElement.el.console.log = function() {}
}
```

tried 3:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" [src]="myurl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen #chatRoom ng-onload="setChatRoom()"></iframe>

setChatRoom() {
        this.chatRoom.nativeElement.el.console.log = function() {}
}
```

Comment: do you try this? https://blog.agney.dev/override-console-on-iframe/

Comment: i can't control iframe

Answer (score 0):

I did get inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28601606/11135174) but changed it in an Angular manner.

in your component.ts, listen to the item with `viewChild`, and `static: true` so you may read the variable into the `ngOnInit()`

#### Inside ngOnInit()

```js
 @ViewChild('myIframe', { static: true }) myIframe!: ElementRef

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myIframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.console.log = function () {}
  }
```

```html
<iframe
  src="hyourUrl"
  #myIframe
></iframe>
```

#### Outside ngOnInit()

To be able to use the iframe like that, it should **not be in an `*ngIf`** because it wont be rendered, in this case you really need to  use it in an `*ngIf` call it after you loaded it.

```js
 @ViewChild('myIframe', { static: true }) myIframe!: ElementRef

  deactivateIframeLog() {
    this.myIframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.console.log = function () {}
  }
```

```html
<iframe
  src="hyourUrl"
  #myIframe
  (load)="deactivateIframeLog()"
></iframe>
```